# Resolving "Authentication failed for" with Git-2.31.1-64-bit.exe to AzureDevOps?

Tags: git, authentication, azure-devops

```
$ git pull
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://azuredevops.<server>/<the_repo>/'
```

Regardless of what I do, pull multiple repo's, clone a new one, etc, I get the above error.

I have not used git for a few days, between that time and now I changed my domain password and went into Credit Manager and removed everything, with the impression that everything would prompt me for my username and password.  Git is NOT doing that.

I have gone so far as to uninstall git, renamed the gitconfig within my user directory, and reinstalled git.  I still get the above error.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

---

Extra info:

- OS: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1443]
- Credit Manager: Thing inside Microsoft Windows Control panel
- Install/Uninstall:  using Microsoft Windows Uninstall and then deleting the directory and all personal gitconfig files
- Yes, I can log into Azure just fine

Comment: Git can make use of credential manager of your OS respectively GUI system. Depending if you are on Windows, MacOS, Gnome or KDE check your standards credential manager.

Comment: yea, I know git is amazingly configurable!  How does that address my issue?  To the best of my knowledge I am doing a clean install and it is still not working.  I simply want to know how to fix it.

Comment: I wrote this as your question is unclear and misses relevant information. First what is the" Credit manager"? Is this your name for a Credential manager? Second what OS do you use? And third what is your definition of a reinstall? If you uninstall a program usually config files and settings are often not deleted depending on the OS.

Comment: Are you able to login to the AzDev portal? If yes, is it the domain user with the new pw, or a different user?

Comment: back from vacation, just updated the Question with the info requested